# Adding the 2nd timestamp shows this error failed to fetch data TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

If I add the `editedAt`, it will throw this error:

```
failed to fetch data TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds')
```

however, if I remove the data where it has the timestamp value of `editedAt` from the database. This will not cause an error. Is this because not all of the data have timestamp value of `editedAt`?

How do I fix this error since I need to display the data with the `editedAt` as well?

And this is the data:

```
const data = [
  {
    createdDate: { seconds: 1647660530, nanoseconds: 228000000 },
    id: "4jnEbtIGLKTgEnJYX7ci"
  },
  {
    editedAt: { seconds: 1647665687, nanoseconds: 627000000 },
    id: "vBBeIQsNbqvbqVWNIK6k"
  },
  {
    createdDate: { seconds: 1646370332, nanoseconds: 678000000 },
    id: "Hs29gnvfeD0cSQkNmsRn"
  },
  {
    createdDate: { seconds: 1645840425, nanoseconds: 486000000 },
    id: "gagdiaihdihaihsd"
  }
];
```

These are the codes:

```
 const columns = [
    {
      name: "createdDate",
      label: "Date",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return new Date(value.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString();
        },
      },
    },
    {
      name: "editedAt",
      label: "Edited Date",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return new Date(value.seconds * 1000)?.toLocaleDateString();
        },
      },
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in your data array should have the fields "createdDate" and "editedAt".

If you wish to not do that, use the optional ? operator to handle no data or check for value:

`if (value) { ... do render } else { ... do something else }`

value?.seconds could return undefined or access the seconds property.